# Change geometry on chapter page

Tags: margins

I got a book I am trying to set up.  In the book most pages don't have a footer, only those that start a chapter do, and this is creating problems with setting the pages bottom margins.

If I don't put includefoot in my page geometry, the footer on the chapter pages gets put almost at the edge of the page.  However if I do, it means all the other pages that don't have a footer appear to have a larger bottom margin then they should.

I have tried a lot of variations of putting `\newgeometry` with `\afterpage` around the `\chapter` command (or even redefining the `\chapter` command to include them. But nothing is working.

Comment: You might try a bottom float.  The type doesn't matter so long you don't use a caption.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I finally found a solution.  I put `\enlargethispage{-2\baselineskip}` after each `\chapter` and got the desired effect.  Just took awhile to arrive at using a negative value for `\enlargethispage`.